# Simple FPGAs application in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am new to FPGA and I am looking for a small FPGA application. I prefer to be developed by VHDL. Can you please help me by giving me a link for a project online?

Comment: What do you mean by "FPGA application"?

Comment: I mean any simple application that has been developed on FPGA. @Arkoudinos

Comment: Check out the page: http://fpga4fun.com/ you can find a lot of simple FPGA based code. You can also use the samples from the FPGA companies, both Xilinx and Altera (now Intel) have lots of example code you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite online, but you can start with micro-projects from book "FPGA prototyping by VHDL examples" (by Pong P. Chu). Personally I found his Verilog book on the same subject one of the most easy to follow. There is also some code online for the book: https://github.com/fpga-logi/logi-projects/tree/master/book-example-code.

Comment: Are you trying to hack me? Your first link is completely rubbish

Comment: Not sure why it does not work now, removed it. Being already hacked, just google for the book.

Comment: Pong Chu makes the code available for download  directly from the [Companion Website of FPGA Prototyping by VHDL Examples: Xilinx Spartan-3 Version](http://academic.csuohio.edu/chu_p/rtl/fpga_vhdl.html) web page.